# Can't display images django

Tags: django, python-3.x

How can I display images from django models on tis page [datat.ru/shop](http://datat.ru/shop) ?

I the source page code see  `<img class='img-fluid w-100' src="/media/images/2.png" alt="img" />`

But only `http://datat.ru/static/media/images/2.png` returns image
How can I convert **src="{{ shop.cover.url }}"** to **static/media/images/** ???

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('shop/', views.shop_list, name='shop'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),

]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Company(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**shop_list.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles%}

{% block content %}

    {% for shop in shops %}
        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <img class='img-fluid w-100' src="{{ shop.cover.url }}" alt="img" />
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
        <!-- <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{{ shop.cover.url }}"/> -->

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you have in your settings for MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: @IainShelvington
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

and this to urls

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Added, but it didn't help.

Comment: Added, but it didn't help. 
It works if I replace **static/media/** with **media**
But what shold I change to leave the previous directory (static/media/) ???

Comment: MEDIA_URL =  static'/media/